# Implement a pager for my table and navigate into it in ajax

Tags: 7, ajax, paging

I'm looking for a way to implement a pager for my table knowing that **I don't use a query** and **I can't use** that kind of solutions:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->extend('PagerDefault')
    ->limit(30)
    ->fields('n', array('nid'));
$results = $query->execute();
pager_default_initialize($total, $limit, $element = 0);
```

I searched the internet, found a clue and tried:

```
$limit = 25;
$page = pager_default_initialize(count($cells), $limit, 0);
$offset = $limit * $page;

$output = theme('table', array(
  'header'     => array('Nom', 'Prénom', 'Organisme', 'Catégories', 'Contextes', 'Fonctions', 'Voir', 'Modifier', 'Supprimer'),
  'rows'       => array_slice($cells, $offset, $limit),
  'attributes' => array('class' => array('table-bordered', 'table-hover', 'history-results')),
));
$output .= theme('pager', array('quantity', count($cells)));
```

The pager is displayed under my table, has the right number of pages, but if I want to navigate, the page is refreshed and my table is gone (that's normal, because of my custom code).

So, is there a way to navigate in the table in ajax **instead of refreshing** the page and passing a page parameter in the url?

I hope so, because I don't see anything else to do in my specific case :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need the [Ajax Framework](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/group/ajax/7) of Drupal. An example that meets your need is [here](http://www.interactivejunky.com/blog/ajax-commands-drupal-7).

An overview of code :

Create a menu for your ajax call :

```
function MY_CUSTOM_MODULE_menu() {
  $items['my-custom-path/ajax'] = array(
    'title' => 'My custom ajax callback',
    'page callback' => 'MY_CUSTOM_MODULE_ajax_callback',
    'page arguments' => array('page number')
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

// Calback
function MY_CUSTOM_MODULE_ajax_callback($page_number) {

  $ajax_commands = array();

  // Create an $html = "do whatever you want".
  $ajax_commands[] = ajax_command_after('#table_id', $html); // html will be replaced in #table_id

  // $pager_html how you want
  $ajax_commands[] = ajax_command_after('#pager_id', $pager_html); // html will be replaced in #table_id

  ajax_deliver(array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $ajax_commands));
}
```

Comment: The pager links have to be modified too, in order to attach the ajax behaviors there.